# MyError extending not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
'use strict';

class ExtendableError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
    }
}

class MyError extends ExtendableError {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

try {
    throw new Error('Oops!');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

try {
    throw new MyError('Oops!');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

The first error spits out:

```
Error: Oops!
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/karl/dev/node/project/exceptions.js:19:11)
```

The second:

```
{ Error
    at MyError.ExtendableError (/home/karl/dev/node/project/exceptions.js:7:23)
...
```

I was expecting the second to state `MyError: Oops!`.

Comment: try `super(message);`

Comment: @pintxo Nope :/

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add this.name on the constructor

'use strict';

```
class ExtendableError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
    }
}

class MyError extends ExtendableError {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
        this.name = "MyError" //Here you put the name
    }
}

try {
    throw new Error('Oops!');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

try {
    throw new MyError('Oops!');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fist exception is being generated, attending to error message, at line 19, this is, just where you invoke your throw new Error.

The second one, however, it's being located at line 7, this mean it's being called from

```
this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
```

And implies that, when you call throw new MyError, an internal exception is produced at this line.

You need to check why that exception succeeds and try to fix it before your system works as expected.

Maybe you should use your super.stack, instead of creating a new Error object inside your ExtendableError constructor